# How do I fix the end Kernel panic Unable to mount root fs on unknow-block(0,0) Error when trying to install and run Ubuntu on virtualbox

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, virtualbox

I am aware that there are questions similar to mine but after spending hours reviewing each one (and the answers provided), I was still unable to find a solution that worked for me. I think this is because I am using virtualbox and am unable to access the right terminal for my virtualbox machine in order to try out the solutions for the specific kernel error that I am having issues with. I think this because none of the fdisk commands are working on the terminal that I am on. Therefore, I kindly request that this question is not deleted until I find a solution to my problem.

Background info: As stated in the title, I am trying to install and run ubuntu on Oracle Virtual Box. I have ran into numerous problems and was able to fix them all however I am clueless as to what to do to fix the aforementioned kernel panic error. Before this error, I got another kernel panic that was about idle kill or something along those lines and I think changing my processors to 2 fixed that error. Prior to the idle kill kernel panic error, there was another error about my Windows Hypervisor Platform settings which I changed using both the "Turn Windows Features On or Of" GIU and the windows powershell terminal (In accordance with the tutorial I was watching). Although these problems may sound simple, they took about a half a day altogether for me to fix.

Current error: Now, I am facing the kernel panic Unable to mount root fs on unknow-block(0,0) Error when trying to install and run Ubuntu on virtualbox error. As far as I can tell, every single solution to this error online requires you access the command terminal of the machine you are trying to install the operating system on (note that I am using virtual box), and input some fdisk commands. I have spend over a day trying to access this terminal and just figured it out, but now I am faced with the issue of the fdisk commands not working on the terminal that I am on. To access the terminal, I go to the advanced options for Ubuntu  which brings me to the GNU GRUB page and then press c. I would greatly appreciate all inputs on this problem. Thank you very much.

[image: Picture of Kernel Panic]

[image: Advanced Options for Ubuntu GNU GRUB PAGE]
[image: Terminal that it brings me to]

Comment: I removed the `12.04` tag from your questions - it seamed very wrong considering the kernel version

Comment: What OS and version are you trying to install? What ISO are you using? Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Have you tried booting into a Live USB/CD on the VM, which would then allow you to access the VM drive and run `fdisk`? If this is a new install and a new VM, have you tried to simply re-install or create yet another VM?

Comment: @mpboden Hi, I do not know the answers to some of your questions but will try to answer them to the best of my ability. I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.  I am not quite sure how to find out what type of ISO I have but the file name is "ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso" I suppose its the amd64 part that determines the type of ISO? I am not using any server so it is a desktop installation. No, I have not tried booting into a live USB/CD on the VM. I will have to find a tutorial on how to do this next, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @mpboden Although this is a new install, I have not tried re-installing anything since I saw a video on general Linux problem solving which stated that re-installing things is a "windows/macOS" way of trying to solve issues. Although it may sound like a trivial reason, I was hoping to be able to fix this problem without resorting to those methods  . However its been a while since I had this problem so Im going to try re-installing as well (before I try rebooting into a live USB/CD).